# warning: [path] the output directory is within an exploded module java 9

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I'm learning java 9 modules system. Here is the directory which I have made to manage the modules and packages for java 9. [Graphic Image listed below]

```
climesoft.widgets [module-1]
com.climesoft.main [module-2]
com.climesoft.math [module-3]
com.climesoft.string [module-4]
```

When I compile the  module `math` as

```
javac -d mods/com.climesoft.math src/com.climesoft.math/module-info.java src/com.climesoft.math/com/climesoft/math/Math.java
warning: [path] the output directory is within an exploded module: mods/com.climesoft.math
1 warning
```

I'm trying to manage the module output as `mods/module-name/package` (i.e `mods/com.climesoft.math/com/climesoft/math/Math.java` ) but I'm facing the warning `warning: [path] the output directory is within an exploded module: mods/com.climesoft.math
1 warning`

What is the reason of this warning and how can I solve it? and I want to confirm that is my directory structure is fine for module managing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a long time since this is asked, but maybe still helpful to someone. I got the same warning once. The `exploded module` means that the directory contains unpacked content of a module. In my case the parent folder provided to parameter `-d` contains a `module-info.java` which was generated before that.

```
┌ C:\dev\java\modules
└> tree /f
C:.
├───bin
│   │   module-info.class  <---- this file causes the warning
│   │
│   └───classes            <---- target directory in my command
├───lib
│       hello.jar
│
└───src
    │   module-info.java
    │
    └───com.example.module.hello
            HelloWorld.java

┌ C:\dev\java\modules
└> javac -d bin\classes src\com.example.module.hello\HelloWorld.java
warning: [path] the output directory is within an exploded module: bin\classes
1 warning
```

In my case it helps to delete the `bin/module-info.class` and run the command again.